# Default JAVA, $JAVA_HOME vs sudo update-alternatives --config java

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, command-line, environment-variables

I am on Ubuntu and I have set the following in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_91
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
>/opt/jdk1.8.0_91

java -version
>java version "1.8.0_91"
>Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
>Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

at the first glance, the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` was not showing my manually installed Java, so I installed it to the command with `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_91 1`.

Now, the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` drops down the list of all Java versions being installed like that:

```
0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
1            /opt/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java                        1         manual mode
* 2            /opt/jdk1.8.0_91                                 1         manual mode
3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
```

But switching between these using the prompt of the `sudo update-alternatives --config java` does not affect `$JAVA_HOME` and then `$java -version`.

My question is, what does `sudo update-alternatives --config java` exactly do after switching to another alternative with respect to the settings in the `$JAVA_HOME$` variable?

Answer (score 14):

It only changes a symlink located (on most distro I guess) at `/etc/alternatives/java`.
Absolutely NO change in the environment variable you set `$JAVA_HOME` is made.

First look at from where the command is found, you can do :

```
$which java
/usr/bin/java
```

The which command shows `/usr/bin/java` in my Debian distro. This file is a symlink which points to `/etc/alternatives/java`.

```
$ls -l /usr/bin | grep java
java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

Then you follow the symlink :

```
$ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /path/to/my/java/installation/1.x/bin/java
```

This shows that `/etc/alternatives/java` is another symlink.
When you do an `update-alternatives` on java, you just change this symlink target to another one.

**Then, why doesn't the executed version change when you do the `update-alternatives` command ?**
I guess it's because of the order the executables are found in `$PATH`.
Since you added a directory to the PATH environment variable, there are now two possible java executables : one in `/usr/bin` and the other in `/opt/jdk1.8.0_9`, but only the first one found will be taken into account when you'll type `java` commands.

And because you set

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The first one will be found in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` aka `/opt/jdk1.8.0_91` .
Because you made `/opt/jdk1.8.0_9` appear before `/usr/bin` which is defined by default in the the PATH variable.
You can check it by typing in a terminal

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/path/to/my/java/installation/1.x/bin
```

You can see that my java/bin dir is located after the others defined in the PATH.

To correct this, you just have to concatenate `$JAVA_HOME/bin` after `$PATH`, like this :

```
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

This way you will be able to choose the default java executable from alternatives and the java exe found in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` will be discarded.
But to be consistent, in most cases you should choose the same java exe as in `$JAVA_HOME/bin`.

Comment: So what should I set `JAVA_HOME` to use whatever version is selected by ALTERNATIVES?  That way whenever I change to a different version my `$JAVA_HOME` is up updated because it's using the same symlinks that `update-alternatives` is using

Comment: You might find this interesting : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584027/setting-java-home-and-path-with-update-alternatives